# Superclass mismatch - for model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I get this error:

`` app/models/result/login_failed.rb:2:in `<module:Result>': superclass mismatch for class LoginFailed (TypeError) ``

It seems that this `app/models/result/login_failed.rb`:

```
module Result
  class LoginFailed < Failed
```

Is somehow colliding with this `lib/services/providers/errors/login_failed.rb`:

```
module Services
  module Providers
    module Errors
      class LoginFailed < StandardError
```

I tried changing the model to this, but get the same error.

```
class Result::LoginFailed < Failed
```

If I change the model name, the error goes away.  I don't understand why -- given the namespacing -- the names are colliding.  How can I prevent collision without renaming the model to something less meaningful?

Comment: where is your `Failed` declaration?

Comment: ```module Result; class Failed < Base```. And then ```module Result; class Base < ActiveRecord::Base```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not proximate to the error.  A file `app/models/result/some_other_result.rb:`:

```
module Result
  class LoginFailed < Failed
```

I was refactoring a little to fast.  Some days I miss the compiler.